# Selenium Webdriver C# - Running more than one test case in VS 2017 from Test Suite

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I have been working on Page Object Framework which will have categorized test suites depending on the page. I have followed all steps in order to build a decent framework.

My each Unit Test, contains one method which follows simple steps. So far I have been able to create a few automated test cases. The issue began when I wanted to run more than one test case from the test suite. I have one chrome web driver instance which is in a separate class. Below is an example:

```
using System;
using System.Dynamic;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace SystemUiAutomationTestFramework
{
    public static class Browser
    {
        private static readonly IWebDriver _webDriver = new ChromeDriver(Properties.Settings.Default.ChromePathDriver);

        public static IWebDriver WebDriver {
            get { return _webDriver; }
        }
        public static ISearchContext Driver
        {
            get { return _webDriver; }
        }

        public static string Url
        {
            get { return _webDriver.Url; }
        }

        public static string Title
        {
            get { return _webDriver.Title; }
        }

        public static void Goto(string url)
        {
            _webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            _webDriver.Url = url;

        }

        public static void Close()
        {
            _webDriver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Each test case when it is run is independent and as good practice shows, there should be no test order implementation because it generates flows. I will place two examples which check simple login operation and login validation. 
Below you can find a class for the login page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;


namespace SystemUiAutomationTestFramework
{
    public class LoginPage
    {
        static string Url = "http://..";
        private static string LoginUrl = "http://...";

        private static string PageTitle = "System title page";
        private static string LoginPlaceholder = "Login";
        private static string PswdPlaceholder = "Password";
        private static string ButtonText = "Sign in";
        private static string ErrorMessage = "Wrong login or password";

        /* LoginPage Elements */

        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "inputLogin")]
        private IWebElement inputLogin;

        [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "inputPassword")]
        private IWebElement inputPassword;

        [FindsBy(How = How.TagName, Using = "button")]
        private IWebElement loginButton;

        [FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "errorMsg")]
        private IWebElement errorMessage;

        /*----------------------------------------*/


        public void Goto()
        {
            Browser.Goto(Url);
        }

        public bool IsAtLoginPage()
        {
            return Browser.Url == LoginUrl;
        }

        public bool IsAtLoginPageTitle()
        {
            return Browser.Title == PageTitle;
        }

        public bool IsAtLoginField()
        {
            return inputLogin.GetAttribute("placeholder") == LoginPlaceholder;
        }

        public bool IsAtPswdField()
        {
            return inputPassword.GetAttribute("placeholder") == PswdPlaceholder;
        }

        public bool IsAtLoginButton()
        {
            return loginButton.Text == ButtonText;
        }

        public void InputCredentials(string userName, string userPassword)
        {
            inputLogin.SendKeys(userName);
            inputPassword.SendKeys(userPassword);
            loginButton.Click();
        }

        public void WaitErrorMessage()
        {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Browser.WebDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.ClassName("errorMsg")));
        }

        public bool IsAtErrorMessage()
        {
            return errorMessage.Text == ErrorMessage;
        }


        public void ReportPageSuccessLogin()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Application Url checked");
            Console.WriteLine("Application Title checked");
            Console.WriteLine("Login Field present");
            Console.WriteLine("Password Field checked");
            Console.WriteLine("Sign in button checked");
            Console.WriteLine("Login ssuccess");
        }

        public void ReportPageValidationTest()
        {
           ReportPageSuccessLogin();
           Console.WriteLine("Fake Credentials entered");
           Console.WriteLine("Login Button Pressed");
           Console.WriteLine("Login or Password validation message displayed: " + errorMessage.Displayed);
        }
    }
}
```

I also have an API class for Pagefactoring. As an example:

```
 public static class Pages
    {
        public static LoginPage LoginPage
        {
            get
            {
                var loginPage = new LoginPage();
                PageFactory.InitElements(Browser.Driver, loginPage);
                return loginPage;
            }
        }
```

Now for the test cases, below an example when a user is on the login page, all elements are displaed, logs into the system, system checks if the user has logged into and closes the instance.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using SystemUiAutomationTestFramework;

namespace TestSuite.LoginPage
{
    [TestClass]
    public class LoginPageTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Can_Go_LoginPage()
        {
            Pages.LoginPage.Goto();
            Assert.IsTrue(Pages.LoginPage.IsAtLoginPage());
            Assert.IsTrue(Pages.LoginPage.IsAtLoginPageTitle());
            Assert.IsTrue(Pages.LoginPage.IsAtLoginField());
            Assert.IsTrue(Pages.LoginPage.IsAtPswdField());
            Assert.IsTrue(Pages.LoginPage.IsAtLoginButton());
            Pages.LoginPage.InputCredentials(SettingsService.Username, SettingsService.Userpassword);
            Pages.HomePage.IsAtHomePage();

            Pages.LoginPage.ReportPageSuccessLogin();
        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void CleanUp()
        {
            Browser.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The other one just validates the login page by providing fake login and password and if the error message is correctly displayed the test case finishes also by closing the instance.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using SystemUiAutomationTestFramework;

namespace TestSuite.LoginPage
{
    [TestClass]
    public class LoginPageValidationTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Can_Validate_LoginPage()
        {
            Pages.LoginPage.Goto();
            Assert.IsTrue(Pages.LoginPage.IsAtLoginPage());
            Assert.IsTrue(Pages.LoginPage.IsAtLoginPageTitle());
            Assert.IsTrue(Pages.LoginPage.IsAtLoginField());
            Assert.IsTrue(Pages.LoginPage.IsAtPswdField());
            Assert.IsTrue(Pages.LoginPage.IsAtLoginButton());
            Pages.LoginPage.InputCredentials("abcd.efgh", "test123");
            Pages.LoginPage.WaitErrorMessage();
            Assert.IsTrue(Pages.LoginPage.IsAtErrorMessage());

            Pages.LoginPage.ReportPageValidationTest();

        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void CleanUp()
        {
            Browser.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Now the issue happens when I try those two test cases from the Login Page Test Suite, one finishes as passed the other one as failed. From the error message, I understand that it is because the other test case is trying to use an instance of the Webdriver which is already running.

I would like to know your opinion/guides/solution how can I solve this problem. I apologize for the long post but I thought that if I place my code it will be easy for you to understand my issue.

Best regards and thank you for your answers or linking me to the topic which either a duplicate of my issue or there is a solution already for it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue on my own. I have created an 
property for my driver class and an Initialize method which is called each time a test class is called. Also refactored my code to be more flexible.